# What exactly are all these English "collate" variants in PG?

Tags: postgresql, collation

When searching through all available "collates" related to "English" in PostgreSQL, I find these descriptions very odd:

```
English (United States)
English (United Kingdom)
English (United States, Computer)
English
English (Europe)
English (World)
```

Only the two first in the list above make sense: English in the USA and English in the UK. But what about the others?

"United States, Computer"? Just "English" without any specification of the geographical place? And then "Europe" (isn't that a bit too vague?) and also "World", which is even stranger when there is a general "English" as well.

What do these actually mean?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to ask Microsoft, because these locales are taken from their C library.